# Check if element has a specific id

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

i am using vuejs to drag/drop elements, and basicly i am using the evt.to and evt.from to know if i am dragging the element to the list2 for example, this evt.to/from returns me the html tree from my draggable element that has the list, so the parent has the id="list2" if i drag it to there, i need to know how i can track if my evt.to has the list2 element with plain javascript or maybe vueJS

tried this:

```
    if(evt.to.getElementById("list2")){
        console.log("IT HAS");
    }
```

i don't want to check on all document, just on that evt.to, how can i do that without Jquery ?

Comment: `getElementById` is a method of `document` only.

Comment: i know, thank you captain teemu :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `evt.to` is a DOM element:

If you want to know if `evt.to` **itself** has the `id`, you can use its `id` property:

```
if (evt.to.id == "list2") {
    // Yes, it is it
}
```

If you need to see if it **contains** an element with that ID, you could use `querySelector` on it:

```
if (evt.to.querySelector("#list2") != null) {
    // Yes, it has it
}
```

If you need to allow for **both**, that's easily done:

```
if (evt.to.id == "list2" || evt.to.querySelector("#list2") != null) {
    // Yes, it is it or has it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly is inside the evt.to variable but you should be able to just do this:

`evt.to.id`